# Como pegar uma variavel que esta no controller e colocar dentro de uma view (laravel)

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

Eu estou mexendo com laravel e dai veio a seguinte duvida. Eu preciso pegar uma variavel que esta no controller e colocar dentro de uma view. No caso estou enviando um email com dados contidos em um formulario.

Basicamente é assim: o usuario digita as informações no campo do formulario ao clicar em enviar o controller recebe as variaveis de dentro do formulario faz a validação e envia o email. O problema é que a view do email esta vazia. Eu preciso pegar essas variaveis do controller e colocar em outra view sendo esta a view do email.
**VIEW DO FORMULARIO.**

```
<section class="form-content content-bottom wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="0.9s">
    <h4>Envie-nos uma mensagem</h4> <br>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.0s">
           <form class="col s12" name ="form1" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('ContatoController@enviar') }}" >
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
                        <input id="nome" type="text" class="validate" name="nome" required value="" placeholder="Nome Completo">
                        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6 ">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" name="email" required value="">
                        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="phone" type="text" pattern="[0-9]+$" name="phone" required value="" minlength="10" maxlength="15" placeholder="telefone (DD)xxxx-xxxx ou celular (DD)9xxxx-xxxx *somente numeros">
                        <label for="phone">Telefone</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="assunto" type="text" name="assunto" required value="">
                        <label for="assunto">Assunto</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem" class="materialize-textarea" required value=""></textarea>
                        <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row center">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn login-button" onclick="return validar()">
                            Enviar
                        </button>
                      <br><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\msgformulario;
use App\Mail\msgfeedback;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;



class ContatoController extends Controller
{
    public function enviar(request $request) {
        $nome = $request->input('nome');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $phone = $request->input('phone');
        $assunto = $request ->input('assunto');
        $mensagem = $request->input('mensagem');
        if(isset($nome) && empty($nome)==false){
            if(isset($email) && empty($email)==false){
                if (isset($phone) && empty($phone)==false){
                    if (isset($assunto) && empty($assunto)==false){
                        if (isset($mensagem) && empty($mensagem)==false){
                            mail::to('construft@sapo.pt')->send(new msgformulario);
                            mail::to($email)->send(new msgfeedback);
                            $this->load->view('emails.formulario',$assunto);
                            return redirect('/contato');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            return redirect('/contato');
            }               

    }
}
?>
```

**ROUTE:**

```
Route::post('/feedback','ContatoController@enviar');
```

**VIEW DO EMAIL**(que deve receber as variaveis para ser preenchido.)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Bem Vindo </title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: é só criar uma página em HTML utilizando `blade` (`{{}} ou {!!!!}`) e as formatações normais, que a estrutura para enviar e-mail via html está como exemplo no site, essa é a sua duvida? você desenvolveu algum código se sim pode adicionar na sua questão ?

Comment: coloquei os codigos na pergunta

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel?

Comment: eu usava o `compact` no laravel

Comment: na controller, na função que renderiza a view você cria a variavel recebendo os valores desejados, tipo: `$myvar = "myvalue"` então na função que faz o render da view você passa o compact como parâmetro e poe a variavel assim: compact('myvar')

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#creating-views

Answer (score 1):

Há uma requisição que o Laravel faz chamado CSRF, Um token para garantir a segurança dos dados.

Na sua view falta isso como primeiro input do seu form:

```
    <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{csrf_token()}}}"    />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em sua View é só colocar assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Bem Vindo </title>
</head>
<body>
    {{$nome}}
    {{$email}}
    {{$phone}}
    {{$assunto}}
    {{$mensagem}}
</body>
</html>
```

No controller seria:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\msgformulario;
use App\Mail\msgfeedback;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContatoController extends Controller
{
    public function enviar(request $request) 
    {
        $nome = $request->input('nome');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $phone = $request->input('phone');
        $assunto = $request ->input('assunto');
        $mensagem = $request->input('mensagem');
        if(isset($nome) && empty($nome)==false) &&
           isset($email) && empty($email)==false &&
           isset($phone) && empty($phone)==false &&
           isset($phone) && empty($phone)==false &&
           isset($assunto) && empty($assunto)==false &&
           isset($mensagem) && empty($mensagem)==false)
            {
                $data = $request->all();
                Mail::send('pagina.da.view', $data, function($message) use ($data)
                {                   
                    $message->from($data['email'], $data['nome']);
                    $message->to($data['email']);                           
                    $message->subject('Envio de Email');                
                });                
            }
        }
        else
        {    
            return redirect('/contato');
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: a versão do laravel é a 5.3, ok muito obrigado, vou testar aqui e retorno com o que aconteceu.

Comment: Deu erro :/  TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 3314:

Comment: O erro é do token algum problema na requisição post nada a ver com o código postado, o erro não é nele, pelo menos até esse momento. @Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

Como o colega disse logo acima falta o CSRF

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('suarota') }}">
        @csrf //se estiver usando o blade só adicionar isso no form
    </form>
```